# Get customer in Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation::getRate in magento

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I have overwritten the `Mage_Tax_model_Calculation::getRate`, so that I want to not tax certain customers. I do not have a special customer class for them.

I have a custom field in my customer model, which I want to check after I am able to load my customer model and if this field has a value I do not tax him, otherwise I call `parent::getRate($request)`

Is it possible to get that in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function getRate($request) {
    // find a customer ID
    $admin_session = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote');
    if($admin_session) {
        if($admin_session->getCustomerId()) {
            $customer_id = $admin_session->getCustomerId();
        }
    } else {
        $customer_id = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session")->getCustomerId();
    }

    // find customer attr
    if($customer_id) {
        $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->load($customer_id);
        if($customer->getSomeColumnValue()) {
             return 0;
        }
    }

    // fallthrough
    return parent::getRate($request);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

---

EDIT: good point ;)

Looking through the adminhtml code, it seems to be far less useful than the normal customer code. I was hoping for a call to Mage::register but that's not happening. I found a possible solution, though loading sessions in Magento seems to have side effects. See above.

RE-EDIT: to incorporate your fixes for posterity.

Comment: Thanks, that would work when a customer is ordering, but there is also a possibility for an admin to order for a customer.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. except a small error. The following line misses the terminating semi-colon 
`$customer_id = $admin_session->getCustomerId()`
Secondly, I broke the test 
`if($admin_session && $admin_session->getCustomerId())`
into two so even if admin_session is true we do not attempt loading `customer/session`

Answer (score 1):

Try this to load the current logged-in customer:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($session->getCustomerId());
$customValue = $customer->getCustomFieldName();
```

Cheers,
JD

Comment: Thanks, that would work when a customer is ordering, but there is also a possibility for an admin to order for a customer.